# C# CefSharp DevTool's close button does not work

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I added the following code to inspect the element in the CefSharp browser using Devtools, but after opening Devtools, the close button does not work

```
public class DevToolsMenuHandler : IContextMenuHandler
{
    public void OnBeforeContextMenu(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters,
        IMenuModel model)
    {
        model.AddItem(CefMenuCommand.CustomFirst, "Inspect");
    }

    public bool OnContextMenuCommand(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters,
        CefMenuCommand commandId, CefEventFlags eventFlags)
    {
        if (commandId != CefMenuCommand.CustomFirst) return false;

        browser.ShowDevTools(null, parameters.XCoord, parameters.YCoord);
        return true;
    }

    public void OnContextMenuDismissed(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame)
    {
    }

    public bool RunContextMenu(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters,
        IMenuModel model, IRunContextMenuCallback callback)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Because of my CefSharp browser is called 'chrome', I tried to change 'iBrowser browser' to 'iBrowser chrome', but it didn't help

```
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser chrome;
        public CefSettings settings;
        string main_site = "example.com";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitBrowser();
        }

        public void InitBrowser()
        {
            settings = new CefSettings();
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            textBoxUrl.Text = main_site;
            chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(textBoxUrl.Text);
            chrome.MenuHandler = new DevToolsMenuHandler();
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(chrome);
            chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            chrome.AddressChanged += Chrome_AddressChanged;
        }
```

I also have class "MyCustomLifeSpanHandler" in this class there are "Webbrowser chromium Web Browser, Browser browser, etc" these arguments/fiels are also present in the class "DevToolsMenuHandler".
Probably it turns out a name conflict?
How do I combine these classes?

```
 public class MyCustomLifeSpanHandler : ILifeSpanHandler
    {
        // Load new URL (when clicking a link with target=_blank) in the same frame
        public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
        {
            browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl(targetUrl);
            newBrowser = null;
            return true;
        }

        public bool DoClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
            return true;
        }

        public void OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnBeforeClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

How do I combine these classes?

Comment: What version are you using? Are there any errors in the log? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file

Comment: Version of my CefSharp is 99.2.140

Comment: Last logs when i clicked close button////[0405/114703.653:WARNING:browser_info.cc(301)] Returning a speculative frame for 30064771083 [7,11]

[0405/114725.344:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(995)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101

Comment: If you add your menu handler code to the minimal example does the problem occur? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: i added my menu handler code as a new class in the "CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms", but when i right click with mouse there is not my "inspect" menu in the context menu....

Comment: amaitland - which version of CefSharp should i install? which of them most effective by now?

Comment: You can try the latest 100-pre release. Still not clear if this is a problem with your code. Did you assign the MenuHandler when testing with the minimal example?

Comment: Testing with https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/tree/cefsharp/100 (uses the 100-pre release) and your menu handler code, DevTools closes as expected. I suspect the problem is with your code somewhere. Do you have a custom `ILifeSpanHandler`  implementation?

Comment: Yes, i have Lifespanhandler class, I have completed my question.  Please read above

Comment: As I suspected, you are canceling popup close. return !browser.IsPopup;

Comment: In the DoClose method.

Comment: Please help, how do I combine these classes? "DevToolsMenuHandler" and "MyCustomLifeSpanHandler"

Comment: What do you need to combine them for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ILifeSpanHandler` implementation is the problem, you are blocking close of the `DevTools Popup` window.

You need to allow close (`return false`) for `Popups`. Rather than implement `ILifSpanHandler` directly I suggest inheriting from `CefSharp.Handler.LifeSpanHandler` and just override the methods you require.

```cs
chrome.LifeSpanHandler = new CustomLifeSpanHandler();

public class CustomLifeSpanHandler : CefSharp.Handler.LifeSpanHandler
{
    protected override bool DoClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
    {
        if(browser.IsPopup)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected override bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
    {
        browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl(targetUrl);
        newBrowser = null;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install latest 100-pre release. It should work in a different version. When you encounter such problems, try to test your code in different versions of CefSharp